# Proposed new tag: Atomic Pi

Tags: discussion, tags

I just asked a question about an Atomic Pi, and thought I could create the tag for it, but I am lacking sufficient rep here to make it.  Can someone make the tag on these questions?  Please/thanks.

- [How to make Atomic Pi with Ubuntu 18.04.2 and Chrome play YouTube videos](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1151937/how-to-make-atomic-pi-with-ubuntu-18-04-2-and-chrome-play-youtube-videos)
- [How to install LUbuntu 19.10 on an Atomic Pi?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1192984/how-to-install-lubuntu-19-10-on-an-atomic-pi)

Comment: Could you explain why a special tag is needed? Especially if there are only 2 questions where the tag is relevant?

Comment: While I only came across 1, a quick search revealed a total of 4 questions on the site so far.

Comment: OK, but why is a tag needed? We don't need tags for every piece of hardware that can run Ubuntu. Is there something that makes this particular thing different? Please [edit] your question and explain why you feel a tag is useful. I am not saying a tag isn't useful, I just don't know, and you haven't given any arguments in favor.

Answer (score 8):

[status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) (at the time of this post)

With only 4 questions there is not enough of a reason to *create* a new tag for Atomic PI specific questions.  We do not need tags for every piece of hardware that can run Ubuntu, and there isn't any arguments as of yet to support creating a new tag *just* for Atomic Pi, especially if there's only 4 such questions.